# What is Nagel's definition of 'The Absurd'?

Tags: meaning-of-life, absurdism

Why does Nagel consider life to be absurd? And correct me if i'm wrong but it feels like he's telling people to live life despite life being absurd? Why does he do that if that's the case?

Comment: "*We see ourselves from outside, and all the contingency and specificity of our aims and pursuits become clear. Yet when we take this view and recognize what we do as arbitrary, it does not disengage us from life, and there lies our absurdity: not in the fact that such an external view can be taken of us, but in the fact that we ourselves can take it...*" You can read [Nagel's The Absurd](https://philosophy.as.uky.edu/sites/default/files/The%20Absurd%20-%20Thomas%20Nagel.pdf) in full, it is very short:

Comment: I have read it and i'm asking the question to gather my thoughts. In separate sections he says its absurd because we take life too seriously.

Comment: You can see also Thomas Nagel, [The View From Nowhere (Oxford, 1986)](https://books.google.it/books?id=5cryOCGb2nEC&pg=PA208), **Ch.XI : The Meaning of Life**.

Comment: I think that there is no specific definition of "the *absurd*. The source is with [Albert Camus](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/camus/) : "The essential paradox arising in Camus’s philosophy concerns his central notion of *absurdity*.  Camus argues that human beings cannot escape asking the question, “What is the meaning of existence?” Camus, however, denies that there is an answer to this question, and rejects every scientific, teleological, metaphysical, or human-created end that would provide an adequate answer. " 1/2

Comment: "This paradoxical situation, then, between our impulse to ask ultimate questions and the impossibility of achieving any adequate answer, is what Camus calls the *absurd*. " 2/2